# Only run a set of models?

Tags: dbt

I started to migrate some of your transformations jobs to DBT. As you can see on the image bellow, there is usually 1 to 2 transformations before to have our final table (up to 5 transformations in some cases).

What I am trying to achieve is to do dbt run only for a set on linked model. For instance, `sales_prediction` and `forecast`.  I am currently able to run either for everything with `dbt run o`r just speficif model using `dbt run --select model_name`

[image]

Comment: Docs are your friend: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dbt allows syntax of

- selecting a node *and all nodes it requires* (`+` before the model name)
- selecting a node *and all nodes that depend on it* (`+` after the model name)
- you can also do both (`+model_name+`)

In your case `dbt run --select +forecast` should do the trick

Also check the [documentation of *the `+` operator*](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/graph-operators#the-plus-operator).

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the [+ operator](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/graph-operators#the-plus-operator), incase you just need to run multiple unrelated models by specifying their names, you can do so [as such](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax):

```
dbt run --select my_first_model my_second_model
```

Comment: You need to add quotation marks: dbt run --select "my_first_model my_second_model"

Comment: No AFAIK quotes are not necessary as they are two distinct unrelated models

Answer (score 3):

In order to run a model as well as its children (aka downstream dependencies), you'll have to specify the model name followed by `+` operator in the `--select` argument:

```
dbt run --select sales_prediction+
```

---

Likewise, to run a model and its parent (or upstream) dependencies, the `+` operator must be followed by the model name:

```
dbt run --select +sales_prediction
```

---

You can also run both the upstream and downstream dependencies

```
dbt run --select +sales_prediction+
```

---

You can even choose the level of depth a specific command will go. For example, the following command will run the model called `sales_prediction` as well as its first and second level children (downstream tasks).

```
dbt run --select sales_prediction+2
```

---

There are limitless possibilities when it comes to selecting specific resources in dbt CLI (including models, tests, seeds and snapshots).